# How to get the different id codes (country, company, etc.) for LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to make a console program to generate the job search URL from a file (YAML probably).

When checking how LinkedIn handles the URLs, company names and countries are not stated using strings, but IDs. I have managed to scrape the Company ID from their page, but have no clue how to do it with countries.

On another note, I have been trying to find information on how to access the API for doing a job search but I have not found anything that seems to allow many different filters to be applied to get a list of jobs.

So my questions:

1. How can I extract all the codes LinkedIn uses in their search job URL?
2. Is there an interface or API page that allows us to do job searches with all available filters?

I have tried scraping for the company's ID and that works alright, but can't do this for things like countries.

Have checked LinkedIn API but nothing seems to apply as many filters as the website does.